# How to display only one pane in vifm instead of two?

Tags: vifm

In vifm, two panes are displayed by default. How do I change it so that it displays only one pane?.I went through the manual to find the vifmrc setting which will allow me to see single pane. I could not find the setting

Answer (score 10):

With sample `vifmrc` file which should've been installed, you get `tui` value set in the [`'vifminfo'`](https://vifm.info/vimdoc.shtml#vifm-%27vifminfo%27) option, which is responsible for saving number of windows between sessions among other things. So if you do <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> and then exit, next time you run vifm it should be in single pane mode.

However, if you want to ensure that it always starts with only one pane, just put this line

```
only
```

somewhere in your `vifmrc`. `vifmrc` consists of the same commands you can run on command-line, so things like `:split`, `:vsplit`, etc. also work (not all commands make sense though), you're not limited to `:set` for settings.